# Does the Linux network stack operate parallely on a multi-core machine?

Tags: network-programming, tcp, multicore, parallel-processing

I have a 4-core machine running Linux 2.6.x. The machine is single-homed (i.e., with 1 NIC).

On this machine, I run 4 processes (or, alternatively, 4 threads in 1 process) that do network I/O from/to 4 different hosts on the network.

**Question:** Will these 4 threads of network I/O be able to run in parallel? Can I assume that the TCP/IP stack (including the NIC device driver) is all concurrent code that can exploit the multiple cores to run completely parallely? At any stage in their network I/O, would these threads ever block trying to acquire some shared resource in the TCP/IP stack, thereby causing portions of stack -- and thus the 4 application-level threads sitting atop -- to be partially sequential and not fully parallel?

Comment: Adding multiple NICs (or a single NIC with multiple ports) would probably be better, as you could bind every port/IRQ to a different CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all 4 threads will do network IO (the big kernel lock is over since Linux 2.4).

You will notice contention on a machine with 64 cores, like the analyzed in this paper (using Linux 2.6.35): https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/osdi10/tech/full_papers/Boyd-Wickizer.pdf , but with just 4 cores and newer kernels, probably you not notice any contention.

PS: Even if you had a chipset or network card that only sends interrupts to CPU 0, packet reception will be distributed to all cores, because it's done in software interrupts that can be assigned to any core. You can use cat /proc/interrupts to see if network hardware interrupts are being distributed across all cores.